# How to read from flow chart

Tags: homework, systems-biology

So I got the following picture and question:

a) Assume that F1 = 10 mmol h$^{-1}$ and the flow is not negative (ie f$_i$ ≥ 0,
i = 1, ..., 8). What is the most you can produce of the polymer DCDE (i.e.  determine F$_{obj}$).?

b) What can be said about the upper and lower limits of the flow values F2, ..., F8 when F$_{obj}$ is maximized?

I thought that you would want everything to flow through F4 and there onto F$_{obj}$ (where mmol h$^{-1}$ would double). However if this was true I don't understand question b, since in that case there would only be one possible flow value for F2,...,F8.

[image]